# Facebook img URL still fetches wrong img

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-like, meta-tags

I'm using the Facebook like plugin. So, when you are on a page and you clicked the 'like button', normally you get all the Meta Data what is in your header. People can like a profile and then the description, title and logo are posted on to Facebook.

Now, the funny part is, sometimes the image (logo) is wrong?
But when I test it on the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), everything looks correct, I receive the right title, the right description and the image.

But when I like, it still posts the wrong image?

Can somebody help me or explain what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the thumbnail image for your web page.
For setting this image you must to include an additional `<link>` tag in the `<head>` portion of your web page like this:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="image.png" />
```

Comment: Dam'n, it works :) Thanks - I was searching crazy for a solution and it is that simple ;)

Comment: sorry, can't do, I need a rep of 15, I only got 7 so far :)